# Internal Testing for Instant App not showing the 'Try Now' Button

Tags: android-instant-apps

Android newbie here.
I have gone through all the available resources to create and test instant apps on google's developer support site and SO. The code (manifests, build.gradle) are all set up correctly. I can test my skeleton instant app in emulator and a real device. I have a single module for both instant and installed version(Is that a problem?). The problem is I have just not been able to test this with the internal test track in play console.
Steps I have taken:

1. Upload the bundle to Standard Track for internal testing. Release this version.
2. Send the opt-in link to testers to verify they see the correct version.
3. Progressed the release to Closed Testing- Alpha. I had to do this because if I did not, I would not be able to upload the bundle to instant app track.
4. Upload the same bundle to Instant Apps Only track in internal testing. Release this version.
5. Share the opt-in link to testers (This is the same link btw as the standard track since I could not find a different opt-in link for instant app testing)
6. The testers see a 'Installed' button on the play store listing. Even if they have uninstalled the previous installed version of the app.

I have been unable to make any progress past this point. Someone suggested in a SO question that it might take 2 -3 days for the instant version to show up, but I have waited more than 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

I can Help with this!

You can test "Instant app" with Internal Test Track, i am doing it, i think its not absolute necessary that you need to have app released on closed track.

You can also have just base module(app) which is instant enabled, no need to compulsory create **Instant Dynamic feature module**

Most important thing in the process is "Enable Instant apps" on Play console : Please follow Step One of this link : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861?hl=en

and create two release using same app bundle : 1. Standard 2.Instant apps only

Also make sure to enable "Google play Instant setting" on mobile Play store,
Google play store -> setting -> Google play Instant

Comment: bro how to add same app bundle : 1. Standard 2.Instant apps only and please explain how to add Instant Dynamic feature module and base (app) auto differentiation by google.